# Formatting a table

Tags: tables, align, arrays

I am trying to format a table but everything errors since I am trying to put a display environment in an `array` (I also tried a `tabular`) environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{.3cm}}l}
Spherical & 
\begin{align*} 
x &= r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
y &= r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z &= r\cos(\theta)
\end{align*}\\
name &
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Next to spherical I want to add the spherical coordinates maybe as a `cases` or just `align` but nothing I try works.  Also, I want it to have a clean look as well in case others know of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an `align*` environment inside a `tabular` environment -- use an `aligned*` environment instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{.3cm}}l}
Spherical & 
$\begin{aligned}
x &= r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
y &= r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z &= r\cos(\theta)
\end{aligned}$\\
name &\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```